# Getting certificate error for SSL certificate with validity left

Tags: ssl, iis

The SSL certificate of my site is not over yet, but its showing certificate error when I visit the site.

Do I need to rekey? I haven't changed anything since the certificate installation

[image]

Comment: A certificate error can have many reasons, expiration being only one of these. If your client does not give you any more specific information about the error I recommend you check your site with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html).

Comment: Run some diagnostics, and the cause should be clear, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I guess the root certificate of the certification authority is not in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities certificate store on the IIS Web server. So you face this issue.

I suggest you could follow below steps to import it.

1.On the IIS Web server, click Start, type mmc.exe in the Start Search box, right-click mmc.exe, and then click Run as administrator.

2.On the File menu, click Add/Remove Snap-in.

3.Under Available snap-ins, click Certificates, and then click Add.

4.Click Computer account, and then click Next.

5.Click Local computer, click Finish, and then click Close.

6.To exit the wizard, click OK.

7.Expand Certificates, expand Trusted Root Certification Authorities, right-click Certificates, point to All Tasks, and then click Import.

8.In the Certificate Import Wizard, click Next.

9.In the File name box, type the location of the root certificate of the certification authority, and then click Next.

10.Click Next, and then click Finish.

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/942061/error-message-when-you-visit-a-web-site-that-is-hosted-on-iis-7-0-http).

Comment: it was working well so far and I haven't made any changes, the certificate is valid for 2 years. Do we need to re-key the certificate every 12 months?

Comment: As far as I know, the server will contains the root  CA, if the CA is at your trust certificate, there is no need to re-key it.